# How to flatten the list matrix (list of lists) in order of index?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, matrix

```
list_data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
         ['hello', 'mellow', 'fellow', 'jello'],
         [2, 3, 6, 8]]

flattened = []
for data in list_data:
    for x in data:
        flattened.append(x)

print(flatenned)
```

gives me:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'hello', 'mellow', 'fellow', 'jello', 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

**How, can I rather flatten this lits to (below) in a most simple way:**

```
['a', 'hello', 2, 'b', 'mellow', 3,  'c', 'fellow', 6, 'd', 'jello', 8]
```

and **to dictionary**:

```
['a': ['hello' 2], 'b': ['mellow', 3], 'c': ['fellow', 6], 'd': ['jello', 8]]
```

Explanation of the process would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` to transpose the matrix:

```
[y for x in zip(*list_data) for y in x]
# ['a', 'hello', 2, 'b', 'mellow', 3, 'c', 'fellow', 6, 'd', 'jello', 8]
```

---

To get the dictionary:

```
dict(zip(list_data[0], zip(*list_data[1:])))
# {'a': ('hello', 2), 'b': ('mellow', 3), 'c': ('fellow', 6), 'd': ('jello', 8)}
```

**Description:**

Dictionary is reported as keys and values, `d[k,v]`.

so, first part `list_data[0]` picks **keys** from the first index (0) of every list, and the latter part `zip(*list_data[1:])` adds the **remaining elements of the list as the values for that key**.

Comment: I just added some description for the dictionary. Just wanted to clarify something for myself.

Comment: The edit looks good. Just the keys don't include the `zip`, the first `zip` is used to combine keys and values into pairs. I modified your description a little bit.

Comment: Just to clarify why is there a simple bracket in this `dict`. Does that matter at all though.

Comment: The parenthesis around the values means it's a tuple instead of list, under most circumstances, it should not affect your result. But you can convert them to list by `{k: list(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}` assuming `my_dict` is the dictionary you get.

Comment: Psidom - Would you be give a little guidance on a problem I am facing. I want to run an `applymap function for a pandas dataframe using a groupby`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171132/is-it-possible-to-do-applymap-using-the-groupby-in-pandas  I think this problem is similar to using a unique keys in dict, but I want to use dataframe since the real data is going to be huge. thanks

Answer (score 3):

**For flattening the list**, you may use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain(*zip(*list_data)))
['a', 'hello', 2, 'b', 'mellow', 3, 'c', 'fellow', 6, 'd', 'jello', 8]
```

**For mapping the values to desired `dict`**, you may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with *dictionary comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> {i: [j, k] for i, j, k in zip(*list_data)}
{'a': ['hello', 2], 'c': ['fellow', 6], 'b': ['mellow', 3], 'd': ['jello', 8]}
```