# Is it possible to do applymap using the groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, python-applymap

In a pandas Dataframe I want to `applymap(somefunction)` using `groupby` (using some column index values).

**mcve_01.txt**

```
pos         index      M1      M2      F1_x 
16230484    141      G/G      G/G       G
16230491    141      C/C      C/C       C
16230503    141      T/T      T/T       T
16230524    141      T/T      T/T       T
16230535    141      .    .         T
16232072    211      A/A      A/A       A
16232072    211      A/A      A/A       A
16229783    211      C/C      C/C       G
16229992    211      A/A      A/A       G
16230007    211      T/T      T/T       A
16230011    263      G/G      G/G       C
16230049    263      A/A      A/A       T
16230174    263      .         .        T
16230190    263      A/A      A/A       T
16230260    263      A/A      A/A       G
```

I have function written to do some analyses for columns A, B, C, D
where the values in A, B, C and D are list.

```
mcve_data = pd.read_csv('mcve_01.txt', sep='\t')

mcve_data.set_index(['pos', 'index'], append= True, inplace = True)
mcve_list = mcve_data.applymap(lambda c:[list(c)])
```

say the function is,

```
def mapfun(c):
if any(['.' in l for l in c]):
    return '.'

if all(['|' in l for l in c]):
    fun = zip

else:
    fun = product

filt_set = set(['|','/'])
filt = partial(filter,lambda l: not (l in filt_set))

return ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in fun(*map(filt, c)))
```

**Finally:**

```
mcve_mm = (mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
    applymap(mapfun)
```

which gives me **(final output)**:

```
pos    index      M1        M2      F1_x    
16230484    141  CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG        CgG,CgG,CgG,CgG         CgG
16230491    141  TgC,TgC,TgC,TgC        TgC,TgC,TgC,TgC         TgC
.....      ...   TgT,TgT,TgT,TgT        TgT,TgT,TgT,TgT         TgT
               .        .       TgT
               .        .       AgT
               AgA,AgA,AgA,AgA          AgA,AgA,AgA,AgA         AgA
               CgA,CgA,CgA,CgA          CgA,CgA,CgA,CgA         GgA
               AgC,AgC,AgC,AgC          AgC,AgC,AgC,AgC         GgG
               TgA,TgA,TgA,TgA          TgA,TgA,TgA,TgA         AgG
               GgT,GgT,GgT,GgT          GgT,GgT,GgT,GgT         CgA
               AgG,AgG,AgG,AgG          AgG,AgG,AgG,AgG         TgC
```

So, this code works if I want to run the function (mapfun) for the whole dataframe without grouping. But, i want to run the function by grouping them by **index** values.

Unfortunately, I don't see any example of groupby and applymap together.

I tried then reindexing the index column and then wrap the function (mapfun) within apply, which didn't work.

```
mcve_mm = (mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').groupby(['f1_index'], group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: [mapfun])
```

I didn't get any error but the function part got messed up when trying to group and then apply.

Output I am getting:

```
f1_index
141.0     [<function mapfun at 0x7fee93550f28>]
211.0     [<function mapfun at 0x7fee93550f28>]
263.0     [<function mapfun at 0x7fee93550f28>]
dtype: object
```

**Expected output:**

**same as final output** but the output (functional part) grouped by the common index values

**Now, I want to take this function and applymap in this column by grouping the data/frame using the values in one of the column or index.**

```
data_groupby = (df+df.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
applymap(fnc) using groupby
```

I tried resetting the index and then groupby using the index name. But, the def fnc() is specific to the data from columns A, B, C, D.
Also, I am not finding any examples and tutorial that uses applymap along with groupby in pandas df.

Comment: This feels like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where `applymap` is your attempted solution to a problem you do not explain. You omit quite a bit like function and real data points. Please back up and explain the real problem, namely original input and desired output.

Comment: @Parfait: Just give me a minute.

Answer (score 3):

A DataFrameGroupBy is a dictionary of DataFrames, not a single DataFrame. You can use `applymap` on the subgroups:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import random, randint

# Dummy data
vdata = pd.DataFrame(randint(2, size=(32,4)))
vdata.columns=[list('ABCD')]

vgb = vdata.groupby(('A','B'))
altered = []
for index, subframe in vgb:
    subframe = subframe.applymap(lambda x: x*2)
    altered.append(subframe)
    print index
    print subframe
    assert(subframe.A.mean() == index[0]*2)
    assert(subframe.B.mean() == index[1]*2)

vdata = pd.concat(altered)
print vdata
```

Comment: Can you look into the question and data once again. I just updated it.

Comment: Just tried to implement your method to fix the problem but didn't pan out. Looks like the way my function for `applymap` is prepared isn't being read cell by cell when doing it with `groupby`.

Comment: Still not a [MVCE], too tedious to debug. `applymap` *will* apply a function cell by cell, that's what it does.

Comment: The only part that needs to be debug is the last one. Where I want to run **mcve_mm=...** with group by. It's perfectly working without group by though. I tried to group the data preceding this code but it later it says groupby doesn't have applymap attribute. I read through several tutorials, still not finding the helpful one. Yeah my analyses needs to be done cell by cell, else apply would have worked. Tried to wrap the **mapfun** with apply(lambda x: [mapfun] x in c) but I think that's wrong. Ahh !

Comment: Hi, Why is it not MCVE. I have given the input and output which are short, plus all the code that was successful before applying groupby. I think I can improve more if you could please tell me what needs to be added. Thank you

Comment: You say "groupby doesn't have applymap attribute" -- you do understand that `groupby` is a function that returns a dictionary? You run applymap on the DataFrames that are *elements of* what `groupby` returns.

Comment: Ok, now I know that groupby returns a dictionary. So, it should be trying to run the applymap separately for unique keys like in dict(list) or defaultdict. So what is the approach to run this **mapfun** on each group of unique index values separately. Any ideas.

Comment: In each cell I am reading two lines (by columns) using **mcve_list+mcve_list.shift(1)** so want to break and continue the function when the index value changes.

Comment: do you think you can help me through chat.

Comment: Looks like I have got the hung of the method you described above. Someway it has worked for my dummy data, but still need to take it to the big data. **Btw, how do you append these sub dataframes after applymap has taken effect.** Not finding any answer anywhere.

Comment: If the answer works, mark it so. Here's a nice summary of ways to [join, merge, and concatenate Pandas dataframes](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html).

Comment: The answer isn't complete though. Since I still need to append the sub-frame after the function is run on it. Second, i need to explain the answer in the context of the input (question). I am still working to get this working on my big data and see how we can improve the answer for future (me or anyone else). But, you input did help. Thanks,